# Send cUrl data without vars array

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I try to post data without setting variable or array. I don't know it's possible ?
When i send $data = array('var_name'=>'var_val') everything works fine, but when i set $data ='to send' i don't get any post data.

$data = 'sample data to send';

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                        

    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: This is php, right? I've added a php tag.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is "to send" becomes a key for $_POST data. To be able to see it, in the PHP file which is $url, do var_dump($_POST); This should show that key value on output. But as you can expect, it doesn't have any value.

You can take the data you have written in POSTFIELDS as raw with

```
$yourPostedData = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://php.net/curl_setopt):

> #### CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
>
> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format '`;type=mimetype`'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like `'para1=val1&para2=val2&...'` or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to `multipart/form-data`. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix.

Simple strings are assumed to be key/value pairs by the *other* end.  Whatever the other end is doesn't see the un-keyed value you're passing.  If this was a GET instead of a POST, I'd say just inspect the query string.  As that isn't the case, you'll want to send the data with a key and a value instead, or figure out how the other end reads raw POST data.  If the other end is PHP, there are [at least two ways](http://php.net/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

POST request does not necessarily contain pairs of `variable = value`. Sometimes it contains raw data. To access it, you need to use the variable `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` that will be filled with raw POST data in that case.